# Insecure bluetooth connection via Bluetooth Advertisements

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Is it possible to connect to Bluetooth devices via Bluetooth advertisment in Android?

I'm trying to develop an application to implement seamless offline transactions, so the payer device, tries to advertise that he's trying to advertise to a certain UID and the receiver/payee device receives the advertisement and tries to connect to the payer device.

Now, the advertisements work fine as per the data received and logged, but the connection never gets established.

The device waits for the connection keeps waiting and the sender device fails to send data with the following error repeatedly after a while:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:952)
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:966)
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:522)
W/System.err:     at ***.offlinepayment.bluetooth.BtConnectionThread.run(BtConnectionThread.java:46)
W/System.err:     at ***.offlinepayment.bluetooth.BtConnectionThread$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Could someone please help us out with this issue?

Please do let us know if any more information is required by any chance

Comment: If I understood correctly, device A (the payer) sends out BLE adverts, then device B (the receiver) scans and sees device A's adverts, but when it tries to connect to device A it fails with the above message? If this is the case, have you tried connecting from another device running a third party app (e.g. another Android device running nRF Connect)? I would try this as this would narrow down where the problem might lie.